# Add and remove class which triggers css 3 animation

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery which triggers a css animation by adding a class of .fade-in.

However the animation only happens once as the class is added once the div's become visible. Im looking for a way to add the class once you see the div's then remove the class once you go past them (no longer in the viewport), so that the animation can keep being triggered everytime you see you the divs.

Here is my jQuery

```
;(function($, win) {


$.fn.inViewport = function(cb) {
     return this.each(function(i,el){
       function visPx(){
         var H = $(this).height(),
             r = el.getBoundingClientRect(), t=r.top, b=r.bottom;
         return cb.call(el, Math.max(0, t>0? H-t : (b<H?b:H)));  
       } visPx();
       $(win).on("resize scroll", visPx);
     });
  };
}(jQuery, window));



$("#step-one,#step-two,#step-three").inViewport(function(px){
    if(px) $(this).addClass("fade-in") ;
});
```

Comment: `.removeClass("fade-in")` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

If a class name is included as a parameter, then only that class will be removed from the set of matched elements. If no class names are specified in the parameter, all classes will be removed.

So try

```
$("#step-one,#step-two,#step-three").inViewport(function(px){
if(this.is("visible") $(this).removeClass("fade-in") ;
```

Refer to the documentation:http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

Comment: I know that is will be using removeClass but I would like it to do it once #myDiv is no longer visible on the view port.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) function that takes a boolean as the second argument. It must really be a `Boolean` though, and not just a truthy/falsy value.

```
$("#step-one,#step-two,#step-three").inViewport(function(px){
    $(this).toggleClass('fade-in', (px !== 0));
});
```

I don't think your `visPx()` function is quite right though. It returns `0` when the element's top is greater than its height, which can happen when the element is still visible in the viewport.

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6gszpkyt/) uses a function that returns a boolean when the element is visible in the viewport.